# Как записать весь столбец Excel в переменную Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Немного поясню , необходимо чтобы циклом скрипт проходил по всей таблице и выводил значение строки в две переменные, образец данных:

| name | old |
| --- | --- |
| Иван | 23 |
| Михаил | 31 |

К примеру, вывод:

```
а = Иван, b=23;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста по коду, как это можно реализовать?
код, который сейчас есть

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
from openpyxl.worksheet import worksheet
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
wb = load_workbook(
    "path/excell_name.xlsx")
# get_sheet_names() - выводит список с названием листов,
sheets_name = wb.get_sheet_names()
for k in range(1):
# for k in range(len(sheets_name)):
    sheet = wb[sheets_name[k]]
    for i in range(2, wb.max_column): # беру со второй так как в первой идут названия столбцов
        name = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
        old = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
            a = [name]
            b = [old]
```

Comment: файл csv? приведите пример своего кода

Comment: Используйте библиотеку `Pandas`. А дальше зависит от того, какой тип файла, например.

Comment: @maestro поправил

Answer (score 1):

1. Не "old", а "age".
2. А почему бы вам не раскрыть страшную тайну, и не показать бы нам,
   что конкретно вы понимаете под "таблицей". Потому как таблицу MS
   EXCEL можно преобразовать и таблицу (DataFrame) Pandas, и в объект
   типа dict, и в элементарный список списков.
3. Поскольку никаких других подсказок, кроме тега "python" вы желающим
   вам помочь не оставили, будем исходить из предоставления вашей
   "таблицы" в виде списка

:

```
tb=[['Иван', 23], ['Михаил', 32]]
for person in tb:
        a=person[0]
        b=person[1]
        print (a,b)
```

Результат:

```
Иван 23
Михаил 32
```

Если же вдруг вам надо работать с Таблицами в Pandas, тогда вот так

```
dbl=pd.DataFrame({'name':['Иван','Михаил'], 'age':[23,32]})
for i in range(len(dbl)):
    a=dbl.iloc[i]['name']
    b=dbl.iloc[i]['age'] 
    print (a,b)
```

так

```
for i,person in dbl.iterrows():
    a=person[0]
    b=person[1]
    print (a,b)
```

или так

```
for person in dbl.itertuples():
    a=person.name
    b=person.age
    print(a,b)
```

Результат во всех случаях одинаков:

```
Иван 23
Михаил 32
```

P.S. После исправления кода ТС, могу только добавить и свой ответ.
Чтение из csv файла в DataFrame выполняется командой

```
pd.read_csv('.....csv')
```

а чтение из xls или xlsx в DataFrame выполняется командой

```
pd.read_excel('.....xlsx')
```

Эта функция через параметр `sheet_name` позволяет работать и с многостраничными книгами EXCEL

Comment: добавил свой код

Answer (score 0):

я не знаком с библиотекой `openpyxl`, поэтому предложу решение в лоб, которое выполнит поставленную задачу, но к расширению не готова, думаю все необходимое по формату сможете скорректировать самостоятельно

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='filename.xlsx')

sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names() # имена страниц
data = wb[sheet_names[0]].values # все данные которые есть на странице
lst = []
for row in range(1,len(data)):
    a, b  = None, None
    for column in range(0,2):# берем только первые два столбца
        if column%2==0:
            a = data[row][column]
        else:
            b = data[row][column]
    if a and b:
        lst.append((a,b))

print(lst)
```